# liferay-ui:search-container-column-button wont react to click

Tags: button, model-view-controller, click, liferay, portlet

i am  using liferay-ui:search-container-column-button inside liferay container the button should point to another jsp with take parameter from the current selected row.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="There are no organizations available">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results 
        results="<%=OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationAll() %>"
        total="<%=OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizationsCount() %>">
    </liferay-ui:search-container-results>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row 
        className ="fff.sem.service.model.Organization"
        keyProperty="organizationId"
        modelVar="organization"
        escapedModel="<%=true %>"
        >

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="Organization short name"
            value="<%= organization.getOrganizationShortName() %>">
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="Organization full name"
            value="<%= organization.getOrganizationFullName() %>">
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-button href="<%=addOrganization1URL %>"></liferay-ui:search-container-column-button>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            align="right"
            path="/html/sem/organization_actions.jsp"
        />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

As you noticed in the code I used search-container-column-jsp to add edit and delete feature for the row. I use a column with search-container-column-button so that each button of that column point to another form, but the search-container-column-button wont react on clicking. What is going on?

Comment: what is `addOrganization1URL` ? can you provide how you create that variable?

Comment: <portlet:renderURL var="addOrganization1URL">
 <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/sem/addOrganization.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Liferay forum posts indicate a potential issue with the taglib:

- [search-container-column-button does not work](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/43550081)
- [Issue in calling an action from liferay search-container-column-button tag](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/40902770)

`grep` of the Liferay source code nor a github search return a single instance where the taglib is used.

My attempts to use the `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-button` to properly call any type (action, render, resource) URL were not successful. In examining [the source](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/be45256a1b44dcc85aba48d579bc2716b068b38a/util-taglib/src/com/liferay/taglib/search/ButtonSearchEntry.java) closer, I believe the generic dump of the `href` attribute value into the `onclick` attribute is the problem.

In comparing the html generated by a `<aui:button>` to that of the `search-container-column-button` the onclick attribute is missing `location.href=`

---

I would recommend using a `liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp` as you have done for the other actions, but instead of an `icon-menu` use a `<aui:button>` if you want the field to be a button.

Including the missing info:

```
 <%
 final String hrefFix = "location.href='" + addOrganization1URL .toString()+"'";
 %>
 <liferay-ui:search-container-column-button href="<%=hrefFix%>"/>
```

does provide a working solution, however, **if this is indeed a bug and is fixed in a future patch, this workaround would then become a bug**.

Comment: Hi I included the action of my previous liferay-ui:search-container-column-button to my previous <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp so i come with tree actions in actions button per row. as i read above links it seems that there is a bug with search-container-column-button